# Network problems in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, networking, ethernet

I have a computer I haven't used in a while running Ubuntu 12.04
I want to upgrade to fix the problems but I can't get a working connection.

During start up I get the message waiting for network configuration.Once started I used to be able to get online by running `sudo dhclient eth0` to make my wired connection work.
I've tested the wired connection works on another machine.

I've tried a load of things from googling to no avail.

Please help. I'm pretty much a novice Ubuntu user. If there's any logs I need to include here let me know.

Comment: what your are using dhcp or a static ip

Comment: Its running dhcp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Desktop means you have to delete interfaces file (auth eth0 or eth1  and iface inet eth0 dhcp) but don't to delete the loopback address.

Then start your services using service networking start

Comment: Thanks. I'll try when I get home. Could you explain why this is?

Comment: in desktop, once you restart the machine it automatically connect the internet. no need to edit in interface file.

Answer (score 1):

This may sound stupid but I had an issue like this and found that if your airport/air travel connection is turned on you will have issues getting connected even if running straight wire hookup. No idea why this happens. Hope this is your issue also.

```
   Artook
```

Comment: I dont believe I uave this feature.  Also its a desktop pc

Comment: This allowed me to get a wifi connection. Though I couldnt find this option until I manually updated network manager. The ethernet was something to do with the interface not being managed.

Comment: ...but unfortunately after a restart its broken again.